# Too many copies of the function to use std::move in C++

Tags: c++, copy, move

I have 2 classes: `A` and `B`. I need to pass instances of them to a function that will push them into a vector. I want to have good efficiency in my program, so I try to use move semantics. So in that function I need `const A&` and `A&&` type for `A` as well as for `B`.
It forces me to create `2^N` number of functions where `N` is the number of parameters to that function. In my case `N` is 2 and this means that I need to create 4 almost identical copies of the function.
Code:

```
struct A {
    std::vector<int> v;
};

struct B {
    std::vector<int> v;
};

static std::vector<std::pair<A, B>> elements;

void Function(const A &a, const B &b) {
    elements.emplace_back(a, b);
}

void Function(A &&a, const B &b) {
    elements.emplace_back(std::move(a), b);
}

void Function(const A &a, B &&b) {
    elements.emplace_back(a, std::move(b));
}

void Function(A &&a, B &&b) {
    elements.emplace_back(std::move(a), std::move(b));
}
```

The code is simplified. In my real code, the `Function` is bigger.
So, I want to know if there is another, better way of doing this?
Hope for your help!

Comment: Take a look at perfect forwarding: https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/perfect-forwarding

Comment: As 1 copy of each parameter has to be made anyway (to add them to `elements`) you can just do `void Function(A a, B b) { elements.emplace_back(std::move(a), std::move(b)); }` The copy of each parameter is made on the function call and then moved into `elements`.

Comment: I assume the `int` data type is just used as a dummy type, since `int` can't be *moved* (it doesn't have any managed resources that can be swapped).  At my work, when a parameter is a **data sink** parameter, we pass them by value.  That way the *caller* can decide whether to *move* or *copy* as needed without writing 2ⁿ functions, which it looks like all your function permutations is trying to mimic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a template function and use `std::forward` to pass on the value with the correct reference type:

```
template<class T, class U>
void Function(T&& a, U&& b) // note: universal references are used here, not rvalue references
{
    elements.emplace_back(std::forward<T>(a), std::forward<U>(b));
}
```